# How can I test new plumbing hidden behind tiled walls?

Tags: water

A week ago, a plumbing installation was done in my house, and the same master glued the tiles. Before gluing the tiles, he did not check the installation. But after finishing with the gluing of the tiles, he let the water run to the end and said that according to the sound of the air escaping - "It's OK!"

Since I have a lot invested in the renovation of this house, I would like to ask you whether it is possible to check the plumbing installation in this way.

Comment: Not testing the plumbing before covering it is a serious cause to be suspicious of their overall judgement capabilities

Comment: I would think it may be a way to confirm that the plumbing is ok.  But I wouldn't rely on it to prove that it is ok.

Answer (score 4):

You find small(or bigger) leaks when the lines are pressurize after the air is let out, if there are any leaks.  Most people check the lines for small leaks before covering them up.

Water and air will escape at the easiest location first, as in an open faucet/tap.

With all the air out and pressure in the line is where the smaller leaks will show up.

To tell if no leaks in a pipe just by air, you need to measure the air pressure at the beginning and after a few hours to see if the pressure is the same.  If the pressure is less then you have a leak.  Just because air comes out only means there is no complete break in the pipe.